# How to mirror a Emacs package repository server?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to download all the Emacs packages from a repository like [marmalade-repo](http://marmalade-repo.org/) to create a repository server in local network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [stephanh/elpa-mirror project](https://github.com/stephanh/elpa-mirror) (github.com). It is written in scala, and from a quick scan of the code, it does the mirroring correctly.

Essentially what you need to do is to download `archive-contents` file from the repository, parse each package descriptor to figure out the name of the corresponding package file, and download it.

The mirror of the repository is nothing fancy: just put everything (`archive-contents` file and all the downloaded packages) at the published URL, and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Found very interesting https://github.com/redguardtoo/elpa-mirror package.

"It will create everything you need (web files, packages, archive-contents) for hosting a ELPA mirror site. Only locally installed packages will be included."

You can even use local file path:

```
# Now elpa/marmalade/melpa site will be overrided
(setq package-archives '(("myelpa" . "~/myelpa")))
```